# Custom Audio Player in react JS - Volume Control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I am building an custom audio player in React JS, I am current stuck with the volume controls in the audio player

Here is my code

Progress bar works fine, What should be logic behind the volume control

```
const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
const progressBar = useRef();
const audioPlayer = useRef();
```

AduioPlayer.js

```
....
<audio
    ref={audioPlayer}
    src="something.mp3"
    preload="auto"
    volume
  ></audio>
// Volume Control Range slider
<input
    type="range"
    defaultValue="0"
    className="mx-2 progressBarvolume bar volume"
/>

// Progress Bar 
<input
    type="range"
    className="progressBar bar"
    defaultValue="0"
    ref={progressBar}
    onChange={changeRange}
/>
....
```

changeRange function :

```
const changeRange = () => {
    audioPlayer.current.currentTime = progressBar.current.value;
    changePlayerCurrentTime();
};
```

changePlayerCurrentTime function :

```
const changePlayerCurrentTime = () => {
    progressBar.current.style.setProperty(
        "--seek-before-width",
        `${(progressBar.current.value / duration) * 100}%`
    );
    setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio HTML Elements have a volume property you can access. You will need to have an onChange event in your audio slider.

Something like this within your onChange method will work:

`audioPlayer.current.volume = e.target.value / 100;`

where e is the ChangeEvent passed into the onChange method.

Comment: Cannot add property volume, object is not extensible  `audioPlayer.volume = e.target.value / 100;`

Comment: Sorry, yeah. My preferred method is actually to just use document.getElementById() after giving the audio element an id. Using a ref object and its current property will also work.

Answer (score 0):

This how I worked on mine

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Progress.css';


export default function Progress() {
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const knob = window.document.querySelector('.knob');
    const progress = window.document.querySelector('.progress')

    progress.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) =>knob.style.left = event.offsetX + "px")
   
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="progress" >
        <div className="path comp"></div>
        <div className="knob comp" ></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```css
.progress{
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;   
  
}

.progress .path{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.progress .knob{
    background-color: crimson;
    width: 7px;
    height: 15px;
    left: 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition:all .2s linear ;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
}

.progress .comp{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just planning to build a custom UI with Audio player it would be better to go with already existing library that makes working with Web Audio API easier.Usually, [Howler](https://howlerjs.com/) is popular choice to go. You could have a look here with reactjs https://github.com/shohinrahmonov/react-tunes